# Angular @Input ngIf and generation of PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, angular7

I have component, where data is taken from @Input as an object - data:

```
 @Input() data: UserData;
```

In HTML I expose data with the code:

```html
<div *ngIf="data" style="text-align: center;">
    <table align="center" #content class="content">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Parameter
            </th>
            <th>
                Value
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Element1
            </td>
            <td>
               {{data.Element1}}
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I added in HTML the button with the function to generate PDF. I tried to add PDF in different ways but I always obtain error.

The last try was with jsPDF and what I got was:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

It looks like because of the *ngIf statement the function does not see the html.
Can I omit this error?
OR is there a better way to generate PDF from HMTL in Angular 7?

Comment: And could you recommend the way the PDF from HTML should be generated in Angular 7?

Comment: Anyone can help?